# Oracle APEX: Interactive Grid with user accounts

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I tried to find a solution to this, but there is no information on it anywhere on the web.

I would like to build an Interactive Grid that shows the user account table with username, <strike>password,</strike> priviliges and so forth. I would like to be able to edit it using Automatic Row Processing, but I am unable to find this table.

What's the best way to achieve this or if it's impossible, at least something similar?

Comment: I know I'm way in the future, but I would like to point out that showing user's passwords in any way would be a major security issue.

Comment: @JustinAudet This question is two years old. But you are right, the password should not be visible. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. The only possible solution is using your own authentication system.